# Why does my lottie animation doesn't show in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, lottie

I followed a tutorial and for some reason my lottie animation is not being shown when I test on Android device.

Package Com.Airbnb.Lottie.Forms was added to all app projects (it's crossplatform)
Then added Com.Airbnb.Android.Lottie to the Android app (first I tried without it, didn't work either)

This is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:lottie="clr-namespace:Lottie.Forms;assembly=Lottie.Forms"
             x:Class="AppWasher.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
  
        <lottie:AnimationView
            x:Name="animationView"
            Animation="26617-ogad.json"
            RepeatMode="Restart"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            WidthRequest="300"
            HeightRequest="300"/>
        
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

This is the guide lottie provides

```
<forms:AnimationView
    x:Name="animationView"
    Animation="LottieLogo1.json"
    AnimationSource="AssetOrBundle"
    Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"
    RepeatCount="3"
    RepeatMode="Restart"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

I tried using all those properties too, same result.

I'm testing on Android 9.0 version

Also json files were added to the assets folder in the android project and build action is set to AndroidAsset
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me after i change the android `Target Framework` version to `Android 10.0`.

And i found the latest Lottie nuget depends on `AndroidX`.

[image]